# Oops! Unfortunately, this merchant no longer accepts payments through Google. We apologize for the inconvenience

Tags: android

when i try to pay 25$ for Google play console developer account , this message 
"Oops!
Unfortunately, this merchant no longer accepts payments through Google. We apologize for the inconvenience."

can any one explain! what this , and how i can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately many of the members are getting this error. Google hasn't personally commented on this. This could be because of checkout server faliure, maintenance or maybe they are completely working on implementing something new, like android market to google play.

All these are just possibilities, nothing is for sure till google personally declare the reason, but since its google, the outcome of this will be sweet :-)

Hope that helps. :-)